# Determine if process started as admin is already running in C#

Tags: c#

I've been trying to determine if `process A`, that I installed, is already running on the machine. `Process A` requires admin priviliges, it is installed in `C:\ProgramData` and it is usually started as a service. There are many processes on the machine, that are named `A`. To find out, if this is my process, I inspected the path to exe file.

You can do this with  `process.MainModule.FileName` or more elaborate setup that is documented in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60698360/get-path-of-process-without-admin-privileges-in-c-sharp)

Unfortunately, you cannot inspect the path of executable started as administrator without having administrator priviliges your self.

Is there another way to determine if the process with the name `A` is indeed the one you are looking for? What else can be checked beside path to executable? What workaround do you recommend?

UPDATE:

I misinterpreted the observations. If the process is started as a service, it is run as a `SYSTEM` user. Because of that, you cannot determine the executable path without having the admin priviliges your self.

Comment: Maybe this can help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5479957/194717
https://winaero.com/blog/how-to-check-if-a-process-is-running-as-administrator-elevated-in-windows/

Comment: If your long term plan is to communicate with the said process you will have to do Inter Process Communication (IPC) so you might just share this information between the applications.